# CMake: recompile C++ program modules selectively based on C macro definition

Tags: c++, c, cmake, macros

I have a program containing several modules, say: moduleA, moduleB and moduleC.
And I also have a single header file debug_flags.h where I define three macros:

```
#define DEBUG_MODULE_A 1
#define DEBUG_MODULE_B 0
#define DEBUG_MODULE_C 0
```

When DEBUG_MODULE_X is set to 1, then additional debugging features are enabled for the module X
(like detailed logging, saving intermediate results to the file, etc.).

Currently, whenever I change the value of DEBUG_MODULE_X, all three modules get recompiled (which is quite costly). Instead, I want only the module X to be rebuilt (since DEBUG_MODULE_X macro is only used in module X).

One solution would be to use three different header files:

```
debug_flags_A.h -> defines DEBUG_MODULE_A
debug_flags_B.h -> defines DEBUG_MODULE_B
debug_flags_C.h -> defines DEBUG_MODULE_C
```

which will be included from the modules A, B, and C, respectively.
Yet, with that solution, I have to frequently jump between the header files
to enable/disable debugging for the modules during development (I have much more than 3 modules).
And I also I do not have a clear overview of which debugging flags are enabled at the moment..

Ideally, I would like to have all debug flags to be defined in a single header file,
but somehow force CMake to recompile only the relevant modules (i.e., those for which the DEBUG_MACRO_X have been changed). Is that possible at all?

I am not sure if this could help: one can include debug_flags.h from the module X
as follows:

```
#define INCLUDE_FROM_MODULE_X
#include "debug_flags.h"
```

Then, in debug_flags.h we know from which module this header file is included. Perhaps, with using this information we can trigger selective recompilation somehow ??

Comment: You want to recompile only part of the source code file?

Comment: @Jorengarenar: nope, whenever DEBUG_FLAG_X is changed, I would like to recompile only the module X. For simplicity, let's assume that the module X contains a single file called module_X.cpp

Comment: So you want Make to investigate what was changed inside a file and depending on changes only re-compile some of your source files - is that it? I have never heard about that being possible but that's not the same as saying it can't done... but I would be surprised

Comment: @4386427: yes basically you are right: recompile only those source files where a particular macro is used. Note that, it's not absolutely necessary to do this in a header file: perhaps, one can define macros in CMakeLists.txt using add_definitions(), and then somehow convince cmake to rebuild only the relevant files..

Comment: As Make looks at the file dates to identify changes, you will need to move the definition to a separate .h file and indicate the dependencies on those .h files separately. So module b is not dependent on include file x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not let CMake add the definitions for you when compiling:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(debugflags)

add_library(moduleA STATIC moduleA.cpp)
add_library(moduleB STATIC moduleB.cpp)
add_library(moduleC STATIC moduleC.cpp)

target_compile_definitions(moduleA PRIVATE DEBUG_MODULE_A)
# target_compile_definitions(moduleB PRIVATE DEBUG_MODULE_B)
target_compile_definitions(moduleC PRIVATE DEBUG_MODULE_C)
```

(Un)commenting one of the `target_compile_definitions` only recompiles that one module. Should you ever need debug flags across modules, you can do something like:

```
if(DEBUG_MODULE_A)
  target_compile_definitions(moduleA PRIVATE DEBUG_MODULE_A)
  target_compile_definitions(moduleA2 PRIVATE DEBUG_MODULE_A)
endif(DEBUG_MODULE_A)
```

and set the corresponding CMake variable.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what suggested @Botje above, I have finally stopped on a slightly different solution which might be better if you do not want to create many small static libraries (for example, if your "modules" contain just few files).

The idea is simply let cmake generate debug header files, as follows:

```
set(DEBUG_MODULE_A 0)
configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/debug_module_a.h.in ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/debug_module_a.h)

set(DEBUG_MODULE_B 1)
configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/debug_module_b.h.in ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/debug_module_b.h)

set(DEBUG_MODULE_C 1)
configure_file(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/debug_module_c.h.in ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/debug_module_c.h)
```

Of course, one can use more complicated constructs, e.g.:

```
if(${DEBUG_MODULE_B} OR ${DEBUG_MODULE_C})
     set(DEBUG_COMMON 1)
else()
     set(DEBUG_COMMON 0)
endif()
```

Where debug_module_X.h.in file is like:

```
#pragma once
#define DEBUG_MODULE_X @DEBUG_MODULE_X@
// alternatively use: #cmakedefine DEBUG_MODULE_X or cmakedefine01 DEBUG_MODULE_X
```

Then, each module X includes the corresponding cmake-generated header file:

```
#include "debug_module_x.h"
```

This way, if you change any of the variables DEBUG_MODULE_X, only the files which include
debug_module_x.h will be recompiled.